# Rust FFI Signature conversion for const pointers

Tags: ffi, rust

I have a C library with functions, operating on an opaque struct, defined like this:

```
Foo* makeFoo(); // create a new Foo
Foo* dupFoo(const Foo* orig); // make a duplicate Foo
```

`rust-bindgen` creates these extern definitions:

```
pub fn makeFoo() -> *mut Foo;
pub fn dupFoo(orig: *Foo) -> *mut Foo;
```

Now, I don't expect the following to work:

```
unsafe {
    let x = makeFoo();
    // Do some stuff with x
    let y = dupFoo(x);
}
```

and indeed there is an error `mismatched types: expected '*Foo' but found '*mut Foo' (values differ in mutability)`

What is the recommended way to handle translating these types of C function signatures?

What does seem to work is either changing the parameter types -- even when the C function uses `const` -- to `*mut Foo`, or using transmute:

```
unsafe {
    let x = makeFoo();
    // Do some stuff with x
    let cx: *Foo = mem::transmute(x);
    let y = dupFoo(cx);
}
```

but I don't know which is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*T` and `*mut T` are no different from one another; they are merely there as indicators of intent. You can freely cast between them: `x as *Foo`.